# mongoose not retrieving _id

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to find a  document from mongo, but the findOne() brings the document with an undefined _id field.
why?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/school');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var scoreSchema = new Schema({
    type: String,
    score: Number
});

var studentSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    scores: [scoreSchema]
});

var mod = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema);
mod.findOne(function(err, stud) {
        console.log('id:' + stud._id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass something to find in your query. For example:

```
mod.findOne({name: 'John'}, function(err, stud) {
    console.log('id:' + stud._id);
});
```

See [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) on how to make queries in Mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

You're not querying anything, notice the `{}` before the callback.

```
mod.findOne({}, function(err, stud) {
    console.log('id:' + stud._id);
});
```

You might want to have a look at the [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/).